# Although i have the right informations there is a thread 1 : Signal brt

Tags: swift, authentication

I have created a login screen for my app and i have chosen a username and password. When i write the wrong infos it works but the right informations don't work please help.Here is my login button.

```
 @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


    if  userTf.text == "bartu" && passTf.text == "1" {
        let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tab")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC!, animated: true)

    }

    else {
        errorLabel.text = "Informations are wrong!"
    }

    }



}
```

Comment: What do you mean with " right informations don't work" ? It doesn't go in your if success enclosure?

Comment: Whenever i try to login with the right username and password. I will have Thread1: signal sigabrt

Comment: So your app crashes?

Comment: Could you show some crash logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to test your variable, because clearly, your are trying to initiate the wrong view.

```
if storyboard != nil{
    let myVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tab")
    if navigationController != nil{
        if myVC != nil {
            navigationController!.pushViewController(myVC!, animated: true)
        }else{
            errorLabel.text = "Unable to find myVC"
        }
    }else{
        errorLabel.text = "Unable to find navigationController"
    }
}else{
    errorLabel.text = "Unable to find storyboard"
}
```

-> This piece of code is not the best way to debug but it would help you to have visual answers to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the two view controllers with a segue, set segue type as push, and then set an identifier for it.

[image]

When you want to push to the destination view controller, simply perform this segue by calling

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", sender: nil)
```